# Sending a very long string to the server with React native?

Tags: react-native, file-upload, saga

I am sending a request to the backend team, they are working with php, so the problem was that we had a problem sending images to the backend, so one engineer suggested a solution, I did not like it but we adopted it and it may work, the solution is to change the image format to base64, a very long string and we send to the backend team and do whatever with it.

When I am trying to send now this image, I see that my request is pending and pending and it is canceled at the end, I think the problem is the long string, I don't know how much letters it has, but it's so big.

So this is what I am sending ?  it is an object like this : ( result of console.log in cmd )

```
FormData {
   _parts: Array[
        Array[
          "key1", "value"
        ],
        Array[
          "key2", "value"
        ],
        Array[
          "key3", "value"
        ],
        Array[
          "base64", "my very long string is here ........ ********* ********* "
        ],
    ]
}
```

I am doing a normal saga call to upload the photo !

```
   const g = yield call(
      client.uploadAnomalyPhoto(
        {
          ...pick(['uri', 'type', 'base64'], photos[0]),
          name: `${photos[0].id}.${'jpg'}`,
        },
        { ...metaData, ReferenceFichier: photos[0].id },
      ),
    );
```

There is where I get only simple data, just simple fields, but I think the long string is the problem.

Can anyone share a solution, a guide, a better solution ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this package.[react-native-image-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-base64) it may help to convert local image into base64. I have used base64 to send local images to backend. I think long string is not an issue.